how should i export the rig to use in AR
so i am in the middle of an internship and i have been asked to learn rig to implement the rig on jewellery models and the jewellery models are going to be used in AR(we can try those models in real time & the models gonna move according to your like snapchat filters) and i tried exporting the rig and the model in GLB format and then tried in facebook meta but its just placing the model onto the face but its not following the movement.
so how should i export the model and the rig? and should i have to add animation too in order for it to work?
i am attaching the .blender file of that model using https://blend-exchange.com/ and that model is for practice so you can download that without any hesitations.

